# Application logs out when the mobile screen is tilted

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a webapp where when i load the application login with user name and password, takes to the next page . But when i tilt my mobile to potrait mode from the landscape , the application loads to the login page again instead of staying in the same page.

I went through few of the solutions and tried few of them , but i didnt find a working solution.

I didnt understand the Retain an object during a configuration change and also the other method.. and i see some of them suggest fragment method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity restarts on orientation change, you can do one of the following

1) Add this code to your manifest (Corresponding activity)

```
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

It tells the Android system, hey mate I am going to handle the orientation change please do not interfare.

2) Use a bundle to save your state variables and thus prevent user from log out!

Comment: Cheers mate, keep coding :)

Comment: When in my app and navigating in some activity, i press the home button of the mobile device which takes me to mobile home screen and when i go back and click on m app it takes to a fresh open of the app [in case of mine the log in page

i want it, when the app is clicked back it should take back to the same state of activity,where it was currently in when the app was closed.

Comment: It is entirely upto the Android system to kill your application, whenever it wants or has the need of. To prevent that you can override the home button. I will add that code in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

For overriding the home button.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the home button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(intent);                   
    return true;
    }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```